# I need to detect touch on a certain view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touch

I have this `grayView` that disables the controller and makes it look inactive courtesy to a previous question I asked, but I need to detect if `grayView` is touched and if it touched get rid of the `grayView`. If anyone can help me figure out a solution to this I would deeply appreciate it. I tried using `UITouchedBegan` and many other stackoverflow solutions but each one didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

`grayView` is an `UIView`.

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:grayView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `grayView`, and when touched, remove the `grayView` from `superview`.

Here's how I would do it.

```
//your gray view
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self   action:@selector(removeGrayView:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[_yourGrayView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Make sure you add this code before you add your `grayView` to your `superView`

Then,

```
-(void) removeGrayView: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) gesture {
     [_yourGrayView removeFromSuperView];
}
```